# MSN Bot written in Ruby

Tags: ruby, msn, chatbot

I would like to program an MSN bot in Ruby and I have found a few libraries that do it for you. What I would like to do is to write an MSN bot ground up. I just want it to write a "Hello!" message to a user for starters. I have written an IRC bot ground up before (in Python) but I can't seem to find any info about how I should do it with MSN. Can any of you guys help?

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Phil Baker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find protocol description here: http://www.hypothetic.org/docs/msn/general/overview.php